# change format of datetime.now

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get the last seen of user and save it to my sql database in mvc5 . I got the last seen in controller with  code like this:

```
users.userlast=DateTime.Now;
```

and saved to my database in this format "2015-08-06 12:12:13.443". I want to get datetime only format day,month,year, hour and minute.

I can't use something like this,

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var text = dateTime.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm");
```

It did not work because my last seen column is a datetime type not string. What should i do?

Thanks.

Edit:
Like whatsup App., i want to see only hour and minute, not seconds as last seen.

Comment: What is `str` exactly? How do you get it? If your column is `datetime`, get it with a `DateTime` in your code and format it to string with `ToString` method. You don't need _any_ parsing operation in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get datetime in format day, month, year, hour and minute only (without seconds, milliseconds), create a new DateTime value before save:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
users.userlast = dt.Date.AddHours(dt.Hour).AddMinutes(dt.Minute);
```

Comment: Now, last seen is saved like this "2015-08-06 14:35:00.000", I don't want to zero at the end, too. Is it possible?

Comment: @mervedemir, you say that `[last seen]` column is a datetime. so `2015-08-06 14:35:00.000` is a correct representation of datetime as string in server default datetime format. you can get a `2015-08-06 14:35` value from datetime but it will be a string

Comment: but when i tried to save a string type in my lastseen column it gave me error   @ASh

Comment: @mervedemir, when do you want to see `2015-08-06 14:35` instead of `2015-08-06 14:35:00.000`? in sql management studio? for management studio `2015-08-06 14:35:00.000` is OK. in UI? somewhere else?  in this case save date in datetime column and then you can select it as string in required format

Answer (score 2):

You say that you are storing as a datetime type, in which case the you shouldn't need to convert a string to a DateTime.  In fact you shouldn't need to do any parsing.

When you query the database you should get a DateTime, on which you can call the ToString() you want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about the format you save in the database. When you want to represent it in your specific format you can ToString it accordingly.

> I want to get datetime only format day,month,year, hour and minute.

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is to use your specified culture regardless of the user's current culture.

Comment: I dont want last seen in a string format and i dont want "ss" and "ff" in time, did i explain well?..

Comment: @mervedemir: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InvariantCulture because your user must be in a culture that uses a dot instead of a colon:

```
DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like that

```
var formattedDateTime = yourLastSeenDateTime.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

EDIT: Try this as you mentioned in comments

```
DateTime dbDate = yourLastSeenDateTime;
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(dbDate.Year, dbDate.Month, dbDate.Day, dbDate.Hour, dbDate.Minute, 0);
```

Comment: I dont want to get last seen in a string format, i want it in a datetime format baceuse of my datetime type column

Comment: Yes but i dont want second and split second... Like in whatsup App. i want only hour and minute